# Trying to Count the Col2 Values Where Col1 Matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I have been trying to count the `Col"B"` number of values where `Col"A" = D2`.

then same for D3, D4 and so on.

I have tried with these 2 formulas but result is not accurate.

```
=IF(A:A=D2,COUNTA(B:B))
=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B)
```

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `COUNTIFS`, where the *second* criterion is that column B is not blank.

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"<>")
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BigBen